# Passenger can't load Sinatra app in production?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

In development and in previous production environments, my Sinatra app worked just fine. But on a recent new server deployment, I can't get the app to load at all under Passenger and Nginx. The response always says:

```
An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
```

[image]

```
    [ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8219 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:381 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] start()
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8219 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1300 ]: [Client 19] New client accepted; new client count = 1
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8219 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:146 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=0, socketPaused=0, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] onReadable
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8220 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:187 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=0, socketPaused=0, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] read 2629 bytes
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8220 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:235 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(2629)="Qfg1DXf7S0eM6fwQcdkHibtnQsZinYKfRJsr8JyIXHGHROd0DdlBSD6cO1OAawed2559:DOCUMENT_ROOT\x00/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current/public\x00SCRIPT_NAME\x00\x00PATH_INFO\x00/favicon.ico\x00REQUEST_URI\x00/favicon.ico\x00SERVER_NAME\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00PASSENGER_FRIENDLY_ERROR_PAGES\x00true\x00UNION_STATION_SUPPORT\x00false\x00PASSENGER_DEBUGGER\x00false\x00PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER\x00true\x00PASSENGER_RUBY\x00/home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby\x00PASSENGER_ENV\x00production\x00PASSENGER_SPAWN_METHOD\x00direct\x00PASSENGER_USER\x00\x00PASSENGER_GROUP\x00\x00PASSENGER_APP_TYPE\x00rack\x00PASSENGER_MIN_INSTANCES\x001\x00PASSENGER_MAX_REQUESTS\x000\x00PASSENGER_MAX_PRELOADER_IDLE_TIME\x00-1\x00SCGI\x001\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x00GET\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x00HTTP/1.1\x00SERVER_SOFTWARE\x00nginx/1.4.2\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0074.73.245.151\x00REMOTE_PORT\x0058922\x00SERVER_ADDR\x00192.155.90.5\x00SERVER_PORT\x0080\x00HTTP_HOST\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00HTTP_CONNECTION\x00keep-alive\x00HTTP_ACCEPT\x00*/*\x00HTTP_DNT\x001\x00HTTP_USER_AGENT\x00Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\x00gzip,deflate,sdch\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\x00en-US,en;q=0.8\x00HTTP_COOKIE\x00fbm_2387994113=base_domain=.mydomain.com; ", paused=0, socketPaused=0, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] processBuffer
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8221 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1315 ]: [Client 19] Event: onClientInputData
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8221 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1336 ]: [Client 19] Processing client data: "Qfg1DXf7S0eM6fwQcdkHibtnQsZinYKfRJsr8JyIXHGHROd0DdlBSD6cO1OAawed2559:DOCUMENT_ROOT\x00/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current/public\x00SCRIPT_NAME\x00\x00PATH_INFO\x00/favicon.ico\x00REQUEST_URI\x00/favicon.ico\x00SERVER_NAME\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00PASSENGER_FRIENDLY_ERROR_PAGES\x00true\x00UNION_STATION_SUPPORT\x00false\x00PASSENGER_DEBUGGER\x00false\x00PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER\x00true\x00PASSENGER_RUBY\x00/home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby\x00PASSENGER_ENV\x00production\x00PASSENGER_SPAWN_METHOD\x00direct\x00PASSENGER_USER\x00\x00PASSENGER_GROUP\x00\x00PASSENGER_APP_TYPE\x00rack\x00PASSENGER_MIN_INSTANCES\x001\x00PASSENGER_MAX_REQUESTS\x000\x00PASSENGER_MAX_PRELOADER_IDLE_TIME\x00-1\x00SCGI\x001\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x00GET\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x00HTTP/1.1\x00SERVER_SOFTWARE\x00nginx/1.4.2\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0074.73.245.151\x00REMOTE_PORT\x0058922\x00SERVER_ADDR\x00192.155.90.5\x00SERVER_PORT\x0080\x00HTTP_HOST\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00HTTP_CONNECTION\x00keep-alive\x00HTTP_ACCEPT\x00*/*\x00HTTP_DNT\x001\x00HTTP_USER_AGENT\x00Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\x00gzip,deflate,sdch\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\x00en-US,en;q=0.8\x00HTTP_COOKIE\x00fbm_2387994113=base_domain=.mydomain.com; "
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8222 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1508 ]: [Client 19] Given connect password: "Qfg1DXf7S0eM6fwQcdkHibtnQsZinYKfRJsr8JyIXHGHROd0DdlBSD6cO1OAawed"
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8222 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1510 ]: [Client 19] Connect password is correct; reading header
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8222 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1358 ]: [Client 19] Processed client data: consumed 64 bytes
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8222 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1336 ]: [Client 19] Processing client data: "2559:DOCUMENT_ROOT\x00/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current/public\x00SCRIPT_NAME\x00\x00PATH_INFO\x00/favicon.ico\x00REQUEST_URI\x00/favicon.ico\x00SERVER_NAME\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00PASSENGER_FRIENDLY_ERROR_PAGES\x00true\x00UNION_STATION_SUPPORT\x00false\x00PASSENGER_DEBUGGER\x00false\x00PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER\x00true\x00PASSENGER_RUBY\x00/home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby\x00PASSENGER_ENV\x00production\x00PASSENGER_SPAWN_METHOD\x00direct\x00PASSENGER_USER\x00\x00PASSENGER_GROUP\x00\x00PASSENGER_APP_TYPE\x00rack\x00PASSENGER_MIN_INSTANCES\x001\x00PASSENGER_MAX_REQUESTS\x000\x00PASSENGER_MAX_PRELOADER_IDLE_TIME\x00-1\x00SCGI\x001\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x00GET\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x00HTTP/1.1\x00SERVER_SOFTWARE\x00nginx/1.4.2\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0074.73.245.151\x00REMOTE_PORT\x0058922\x00SERVER_ADDR\x00192.155.90.5\x00SERVER_PORT\x0080\x00HTTP_HOST\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00HTTP_CONNECTION\x00keep-alive\x00HTTP_ACCEPT\x00*/*\x00HTTP_DNT\x001\x00HTTP_USER_AGENT\x00Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\x00gzip,deflate,sdch\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\x00en-US,en;q=0.8\x00HTTP_COOKIE\x00fbm_2387994113=base_domain=.mydomain.com; "
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8224 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1775 ]: [Client 19] Valid SCGI header; not buffering request body; checking out session
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8225 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:367 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(2629)="Qfg1DXf7S0eM6fwQcdkHibtnQsZinYKfRJsr8JyIXHGHROd0DdlBSD6cO1OAawed2559:DOCUMENT_ROOT\x00/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current/public\x00SCRIPT_NAME\x00\x00PATH_INFO\x00/favicon.ico\x00REQUEST_URI\x00/favicon.ico\x00SERVER_NAME\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00PASSENGER_FRIENDLY_ERROR_PAGES\x00true\x00UNION_STATION_SUPPORT\x00false\x00PASSENGER_DEBUGGER\x00false\x00PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER\x00true\x00PASSENGER_RUBY\x00/home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby\x00PASSENGER_ENV\x00production\x00PASSENGER_SPAWN_METHOD\x00direct\x00PASSENGER_USER\x00\x00PASSENGER_GROUP\x00\x00PASSENGER_APP_TYPE\x00rack\x00PASSENGER_MIN_INSTANCES\x001\x00PASSENGER_MAX_REQUESTS\x000\x00PASSENGER_MAX_PRELOADER_IDLE_TIME\x00-1\x00SCGI\x001\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x00GET\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x00HTTP/1.1\x00SERVER_SOFTWARE\x00nginx/1.4.2\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0074.73.245.151\x00REMOTE_PORT\x0058922\x00SERVER_ADDR\x00192.155.90.5\x00SERVER_PORT\x0080\x00HTTP_HOST\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00HTTP_CONNECTION\x00keep-alive\x00HTTP_ACCEPT\x00*/*\x00HTTP_DNT\x001\x00HTTP_USER_AGENT\x00Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\x00gzip,deflate,sdch\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\x00en-US,en;q=0.8\x00HTTP_COOKIE\x00fbm_2387994113=base_domain=.mydomain.com; ", paused=0, socketPaused=0, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] stop()
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8225 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1860 ]: [Client 19] Checking out session: appRoot=/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8226 30156/7f379e621700 Pool2/Pool.h:941 ]: asyncGet(appRoot=/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current)
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8226 30156/7f379e621700 Pool2/Pool.h:946 ]: Found existing SuperGroup
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8227 30156/7f379e621700 Pool2/Group.h:1003 ]: Requested spawning of new process for group /home/avishai/apps/myapp/current#default
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8229 30156/7f379e621700 Pool2/Group.h:727 ]: No session checked out yet: group is spawning or restarting
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8229 30156/7f379e621700 Pool2/Pool.h:951 ]: asyncGet() finished
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8229 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/DirectSpawner.h:168 ]: Spawning new process: appRoot=/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8229 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1358 ]: [Client 19] Processed client data: consumed 2565 bytes
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8229 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:251 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(2629)="Qfg1DXf7S0eM6fwQcdkHibtnQsZinYKfRJsr8JyIXHGHROd0DdlBSD6cO1OAawed2559:DOCUMENT_ROOT\x00/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current/public\x00SCRIPT_NAME\x00\x00PATH_INFO\x00/favicon.ico\x00REQUEST_URI\x00/favicon.ico\x00SERVER_NAME\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00PASSENGER_FRIENDLY_ERROR_PAGES\x00true\x00UNION_STATION_SUPPORT\x00false\x00PASSENGER_DEBUGGER\x00false\x00PASSENGER_SHOW_VERSION_IN_HEADER\x00true\x00PASSENGER_RUBY\x00/home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby\x00PASSENGER_ENV\x00production\x00PASSENGER_SPAWN_METHOD\x00direct\x00PASSENGER_USER\x00\x00PASSENGER_GROUP\x00\x00PASSENGER_APP_TYPE\x00rack\x00PASSENGER_MIN_INSTANCES\x001\x00PASSENGER_MAX_REQUESTS\x000\x00PASSENGER_MAX_PRELOADER_IDLE_TIME\x00-1\x00SCGI\x001\x00QUERY_STRING\x00\x00REQUEST_METHOD\x00GET\x00SERVER_PROTOCOL\x00HTTP/1.1\x00SERVER_SOFTWARE\x00nginx/1.4.2\x00REMOTE_ADDR\x0074.73.245.151\x00REMOTE_PORT\x0058922\x00SERVER_ADDR\x00192.155.90.5\x00SERVER_PORT\x0080\x00HTTP_HOST\x00myapp.mydomain.com\x00HTTP_CONNECTION\x00keep-alive\x00HTTP_ACCEPT\x00*/*\x00HTTP_DNT\x001\x00HTTP_USER_AGENT\x00Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING\x00gzip,deflate,sdch\x00HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE\x00en-US,en;q=0.8\x00HTTP_COOKIE\x00fbm_2387994113=base_domain=.mydomain.com; ", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] Consumed 2629 bytes
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:23.8242 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/DirectSpawner.h:215 ]: Process forked for appRoot=/home/avishai/apps/myapp/current: PID 27926
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0347 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 27926 stdout] 
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0645 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:730 ]: [App 27926 stdout] !> I have control 1.0
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0647 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] You have control 1.0
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0647 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] passenger_root: /home/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.13
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0647 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] passenger_version: 4.0.13
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0647 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] ruby_libdir: /home/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.13/lib
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0647 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] generation_dir: /tmp/passenger.1.0.28678/generation-2
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0648 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] gupid: 15e5325-z9yuDukpx5Y
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0648 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] connect_password: WZNa6zCGDSYtg5s5Tkq1A3ZkGPM8waBmnfxyirdEYVs
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0648 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] app_root: /home/avishai/apps/myapp/current
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0648 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] app_group_name: /home/avishai/apps/myapp/current
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0648 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] app_type: rack
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] start_command: /home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby   /home/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.13/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] startup_file: config.ru
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] process_title: Passenger RackApp
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] log_level: 3
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] start_timeout: 90000
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] environment: production
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0649 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] base_uri: /
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] spawn_method: direct
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] default_user: nobody
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] default_group: nogroup
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] ruby: /home/avishai/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429/ruby
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] python: python
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0650 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] logging_agent_address: unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.28678/generation-2/logging
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] logging_agent_username: logging
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] logging_agent_password: KvYl30DO9TVmT7RfAk09iCgcmzwDBxwibkgpQQ9Xnt3j4fsqECOLLpBSpx4yX2gn
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] debugger: false
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] analytics: false
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] group_secret: gUTSaf7irRGfmV6AgdCgg66SfuvB9aOROvzPm2rGdjw
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:24.0651 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Spawner.h:404 ]: [App 27926 stdin >>] 
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:25.1863 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:25.1864 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.814 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:30.0005 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:30.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:34.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:34.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:37.2055 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:39.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:39.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:44.0001 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:44.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:50.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:50.0005 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:52.2057 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:55.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:55.0007 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:59.0004 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:05:59.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:02.4117 30156/7f37a05e3700 Pool2/Pool.h:608 ]: Garbage collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:02.4118 30156/7f37a05e3700 Pool2/Pool.h:657 ]: Garbage collection done; next garbage collect in 300.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:04.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:04.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:07.2063 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:09.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:09.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:14.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:14.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:19.0004 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:19.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:22.2058 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:24.0004 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:24.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:29.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:29.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:34.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:34.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:37.2050 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:39.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:39.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:45.1031 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:45.1032 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.897 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:49.0004 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:50.0006 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 4.999 sec
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:52.2052 30165/7f9d9d79a780 agents/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:744 ]: Flushing all sinks
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9324 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:767 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/avishai/apps/myapp/current#default: An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::throwAppSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:666)
     in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::negotiateSpawn(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1133)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::DirectSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (DirectSpawner.h:213)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:700)

[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9325 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Group.h:446 ]: Enabling all DISABLING processes with result DR_ERROR
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9325 30156/7f37a04ff700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:786 ]: Spawn loop done
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9326 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1896 ]: [Client 19] Cannot checkout session. An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9329 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1162 ]: [Client 19] Forwarding 187 bytes of application data to client.
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9329 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1182 ]: [Client 19] Managed to forward 187 bytes.
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9330 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1162 ]: [Client 19] Forwarding 3326 bytes of application data to client.
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9330 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1182 ]: [Client 19] Managed to forward 3326 bytes.
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9330 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1192 ]: [Client 19] Client output pipe ended; disconnecting client
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9330 30156/7f379e621700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:576 ]: [Client 19] Disconnected; new client count = 0
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9331 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:353 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784002a50 fd=-1, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=1, error=0] destroyed
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:53.9331 30156/7f379e621700 EventedBufferedInput.h:353 ]: [EventedBufferedInput 0x7f3784000980 fd=19, state=LIVE, buffer(0)="", paused=1, socketPaused=1, nextTickInstalled=0, generation=2, error=0] destroyed
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:55.0002 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:723 ]: Analytics collection time...
[ 2013-08-26 16:06:55.0003 30156/7f37a0624700 Pool2/Pool.h:827 ]: Analytics collection done; next analytics collection in 5.000 sec
```

I removed all logging code referencing STDOUT in my application code. How can I get the app to boot properly?

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple reasons why this happens.

"[Debugging application startup problems](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems)" from the Phusion Passenger wiki explains how you can debug startup timeout problems.